# "The Drude is on board with this"

Tags: meaning, phrases

In this [comment](http://drupal.org/node/1046668#comment-4029266), the author uses the expression *the Drude is on board with this*.

What does it mean?

Comment: just came across http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude but none of this makes much sense either in the Drupal context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, since I'm not familiar with Drupal, but my immediate reaction was that "Drude" was a portmanteau of "Druid" and "Dude", which would be somewhat in keeping with the Wikipedia definition, and connoting some sort of hip wizard, with the additional benefit of the initial "dr" reflecting Drupal as well.

Answer (score 2):

'The Drude' would seem to be a moderator or someone important on Drupal.org (*Dr*upal + dude I'd imagine).

The phrase 'get on board' means that someone has agreed to cooperate with or support something. E.g.

> The plan is in place and the Navy is on board with it.

or

> We've got a new product idea, we just need to get the boss on board with it.

Comment: _Drude_ is not a word normally used to mean a user with particular permissions on drupal.org. The "initiative" has not be done on drupal.org, but in another place/country. I was thinking of a typo (i.e., the user really meant _dude_), but he wrote the word in capital.

Comment: No, but I mean it could be the user name, like 'kiamlaluno', of a particular moderator. 'Kiamlaluno is on board with this.'

Comment: That's the first think I checked, but _Drude_ is not a username on drupal.org. **:-)**

Comment: Yes it is: https://drupal.org/user/773686 . In any case, it is not an English word. I am 99.999999% sure it refers to someone (or a group of people) involved with the Drupal project, purely because of the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably a joining of *Drupal* and *The Dude* (a/k/a Jeff Bridges' character in *The Big Lebowski*).

[image]

Either that's someone's chosen screen name or the fictional embodiment of some familial spirit that stalks the Drupal board in question. OK, maybe "slouches through" the boards is a better way to put it.

But that's, well, like, you know, just my opinion, man.